# If $UU^*=I$ is the unitary group, what is $(UU^*)^2=1$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, physics, unitary-matrices

Let $U$ be a $n\times n$ complex matrix satisfying:

$$
UU^*UU^*=I
$$

Does it follow that $UU^*=I$?

---

Let me have a go at it:

$$
UU^*UU^*=(UU^*)^2=I\implies UU^*=\pm \sqrt{I}
$$

Now the square root of $I$ is the set of all matrices $A^2=I$.

Does this "group" have any interesting properties, notably in physics?

Comment: Have a look at [involutory matrices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix).

Answer (score 4):

By the given condition, both $UU^\ast$ and $I$ are positive semidefinite square roots of $I$. Since each PSD matrix has a unique PSD square root, we have $UU^\ast=I$, i.e., $U$ is simply a unitary matrix.